# C# List of float arrays output is different depending on breakpoint placement

Tags: c#, list, debugging, breakpoints

I'm working on creating a genetic algorithm solution to the traveling salesman problem in C# and in order to do that I'm trying to create a List of Lists of float arrays, or a `List<List<float[]>>` if that helps.

I've got a function called `RandomInitialPopulation` which takes in a `List<float[]> xyCoordinates` and an `int populationSize` and outputs a List with a populationSize number of elements, where each element is an object with a random permutation of the `List<float[]> xyCoordinates` and the total distance involved in traversing the list of xyCoordinates in that order

In order to create the random permutations for each element I've got another function called `ShuffleList` that takes in `List<float[]> arrayToShuffle` and outputs a random permutation of that List

ShuffleList is called n times, where n = populationSize. The problem I've noticed is that if I just run my code with no breakpoints, all n outputs from ShuffleList are the exact same. But if I place a breakpoint on the return statement, and repeatedly hit F5 n number of times, ShuffleList produces a different permutation each time, which is the behavior I want it to do.

Here's my code, I can't for the life of me figure out why this code is behaving the way it is.

```
    private List<PopulationMember> RandomInitialPopulation(List<float[]> xyCoordinates, int populationSize)
    {
        List<PopulationMember> population = new List<PopulationMember>();
        for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
        {
            PopulationMember populationMember = new PopulationMember();
            populationMember.Path = ShuffleList(xyCoordinates);
            populationMember.TotalDistance = GetPathDistance(populationMember.Path);
            population.Add(populationMember);
        }
        return population;
    }

    private List<float[]> ShuffleList(List<float[]> arrayToShuffle)
    {
        List<float[]> tempCollection = new List<float[]>(arrayToShuffle);
        List<float[]> shuffledXYCoordinatesArray = new List<float[]>();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        while (tempCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            int num = rnd.Next(tempCollection.Count);
            shuffledXYCoordinatesArray.Add(tempCollection.ElementAt(num));
            tempCollection.RemoveAt(num);
        }
        return shuffledXYCoordinatesArray;
    }
```

Here's the code for the PopulationMember object as well

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TravelingSalesman
{
    public class PopulationMember
    {
        public List<float[]> Path { get; set; }

        public float TotalDistance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's some screenshots too:

Here's what I'm seeing if I just run ShuffleList with no breakpoints

[image]

You can tell the `Path` Lists are all the same because the `TotalDistance` is the same for each one

But here's what I'm seeing if I leave a breakpoint on the return statement on ShuffleList and hit it everytime it runs, pressing F5 each time

[image]

This is the behavior I want

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: .NET framework 4.7.2

Comment: You need to create a Random instance just once (e.g. make it as a class variable), then use it for all your calls.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0#instantiating-the-random-number-generator

Comment: Or you can switch to .NET Core which doesn't have this "issue"

Comment: Your `ShuffleList` method is awful. Pulling apart the `tempCollection` is terribly inefficient. Use a Fisher-Yates shuffle. It's much much more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Have a single static `Random` object created once.

When you initialise multiple `Random` objects very close to each other in time then they get the same seed and `Next` produces the same number.

When you debug, you slow things down and `new Random()` gets a new different seed so the numbers are different.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you need a single static `Random` object to avoid duplication in the random numbers being generated when the instances of `Random` are created in quick succession.

Here's a better implementation to work from:

```
private List<PopulationMember> RandomInitialPopulation(List<float[]> xyCoordinates, int populationSize) =>
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, populationSize)
        .Select(i => ShuffleList(xyCoordinates))
        .Select(x => new PopulationMember()
        {
            Path = x,
            TotalDistance = GetPathDistance(x)
        })
        .ToList();

private static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> rnd =
    new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random());

private List<float[]> ShuffleList(List<float[]> arrayToShuffle)
{
    var output = arrayToShuffle.ToList();
    for (var i = 0; i < output.Count; i++)
    {
        var j = rnd.Value.Next(i, output.Count);
        (output[i], output[j]) = (output[j], output[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

And, if you're OK, with a slight loss of efficiency, then you could just do this:

```
private List<PopulationMember> RandomInitialPopulation(List<float[]> xyCoordinates, int populationSize) =>
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, populationSize)
        .Select(i => xyCoordinates.OrderBy(x => rnd.Value.Next()).ToList())
        .Select(x => new PopulationMember()
        {
            Path = x,
            TotalDistance = GetPathDistance(x)
        })
        .ToList();

private static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> rnd =
    new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random());
```